# カメラボードの3D-CADデータにカメラ本体の部品がない

Tags: spresense

下記でカメラボードの3Dデータ(STL)をダウンロードしました。

https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/hw_docs_ja.html

CAD(Rhinoceros6)でみると、肝心のカメラの部品（レンズと胴体の黒いもの）がついていないです。

小さなIC、コンデンサ等はついています。

CADによる問題なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

ご指摘ありがとうございます。

早速、3D CADファイルにカメラモジュール部分を追加いたしました。
[3D CADデータ(STEP) (stp)](https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-hw-design-files/raw/master/CXD5602PWBCAM1/stp/CXD5602PWBCAM1.stp)

この度はドキュメントの不備によってご不便をお掛け致しました。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
SPRESENSEサポートチーム